# Conditionally update multiple values without insert

Tags: mysql, sql

Given a set of data, how do I update all rows matching the same `id` with values that are greater than what already exist, without inserting any extra rows?

This is my table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `contacts` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

The table has these rows:

| id | date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-01-01 10:00:00 |
| 2 | null |
| 3 | 2019-10-01 10:00:00 |
| 4 | 2019-10-01 10:00:00 |

The data in my program (json):

```json
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "date": "2020-01-01 13:00:00"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "date": "2020-01-01 14:00:00"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "date": "2020-01-01 14:00:00"
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "date": "2020-01-01 14:00:00"
  }
]
```

I want to achieve this:

| id | date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-01-01 10:00:00 |
| 2 | 2020-01-01 14:00:00 |
| 3 | 2020-01-01 14:00:00 |
| 4 | 2019-10-01 10:00:00 |

In the result, rows without matching `id` should not be inserted. Rows already having a greater `date` should not be updated.

I am using MySQL 8.0.26

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve it is to construct a table from the values and join on it. Then use `GREATER` to update with the greatest value chosen between what already exists on `contacts` and the constructed table `t2`.

```sql
UPDATE contacts
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT * FROM (VALUES
    ROW(1, '2020-01-01 13:00:00'),
    ROW(2, '2020-01-01 14:00:00'),
    ROW(3, '2020-01-01 14:00:00'),
    ROW(5, '2020-01-01 14:00:00')
  ) AS t1(id, date)
) AS t2 ON contacts.id = t2.id
SET contacts.date = GREATEST(COALESCE(contacts.date, 0), t2.date)
```

Note this solution only works for MySQL versions greater than 8.0.19, since that is when the VALUES statement was introduced.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/values.html

Comment: Source data is solid JSON, not ROW constructor, in the question at least...

Answer (score 0):

```sql
UPDATE contacts
JOIN JSON_TABLE (@source_data,
                 '$[*]' COLUMNS (id INT PATH '$.id',
                                 `date` DATETIME PATH '$.date')) src USING (id)
SET contacts.`date` = CASE WHEN contacts.`date` > src.`date`
                           THEN contacts.`date`
                           ELSE src.`date`
                           END;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a779d637c09197cdc6a2e7c75aef731b